# Migrate data from Microsoft SQL to Elasticsearch using ODBC

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, jdbc, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to migrate some data from MS SQL server to Elasticsearch. I see various resources online that use JDBC & Logstash config, however I want to find a way to do the whole process using ODBC connection. I've used ODBC in MS Access to connect to the SQL server database.

1. Is there a way to migrate the data in MS Access to my Elasticsearch index using ODBC?
2. In case using JDBC is the only option, will there be any limitations like sticking to using Java for any changes/implementations?

Comment: Does Elasticsearch have an ODBC driver?

Comment: @GordThompson YEs, it does. [link](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/elasticsearch/odbc/)

Comment: Okay, so that's a good start. If you already have the data available via an Access database have you tried creating an ODBC linked table for the Elasticsearch table and then running an "Update query" in Access?

Comment: @GordThompson I see 'Linked Table Manager' option but it doesn't show me anything related to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @GordThompson Are you saying that as I imported data to Access using SQL ODBC, similarly I can export data using Elasticsearch ODBC?

Comment: `External Data > Export > ODBC Database` is one option (for creating a new table in the target database). Linked Table Manager is for reconfiguring existing linked tables; to create a new linked table use `External Data > Import & Link > ODBC Database`

Comment: @GordThompson I installed the ODBC driver from the link I sent before but will download from the Elasticsearch own site [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-odbc-installation.html) It has some additional steps but I hope at the end I get to see 'Elasticsearch driver' in my data source list.

Comment: can you use SSIS? fast, easy and manage load balance .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can migrate the data in Ms Access file to Elasticsearch index using driver UCanAccess and Logstash

Comment: Hi dear friend. for give best feedback for activities here you should read about this site. your answer need complete , please read about in help center  :   https://stackoverflow.com/help and read this and give a bronze badge :  https://stackoverflow.com/tour